# sed - Search and replace always puts capture group at the end

Tags: sed, xargs, ag

I'm refactoring some code across lots of files, and am trying to do a search and replace using `sed` on a Mac.

The goal is to go from this:

`fooActions: typeof fooActionCreators`

to this:

`fooActions: Partial<typeof fooActionCreators>`

I've gotten it to mostly work using this sed expression:

`ag -l "Actions: typeof " | xargs sed -i "" -e "s/Actions: typeof \(\w*\)/Actions: Partial<typeof \1>/g"`

Basically using `ag` to find the list of file names containing a matching string, then use `xargs` to pass those as input to my `sed` expression.

The output I get though looks like this:
`fooActions: Partial<typeof >fooActionCreators`

I can't figure out why my capture group is being placed at then end instead of where I have it in the replace clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed that comes with mac doesn't support `\w` for word characters.

If you have gsed (gnu sed) this should work as expected.

```
$ echo 'Actions: typeof foo' |  gsed  -e "s/Actions: typeof \(\w*\)/Actions: Partial<typeof \1>/g"
Actions: Partial<typeof foo>
```

Otherwise you can use something like `[a-zA-Z]*` instead of `\w*`.

```
$ echo 'Actions: typeof foo' |  sed  -e "s/Actions: typeof \([a-zA-Z]*\)/Actions: Partial<typeof \1>/g"
Actions: Partial<typeof foo>
```

The seemingly odd behavior that you're seeing is because in the plain sed version, the `\w*` is matching the empty string in front of the thing you're hoping to match, as illustrated below:

Plain sed matches empty string in front of `a`

```
$ echo a | sed "s/\(\w*\)/\1x/"
xa
```

Gnu sed matches the `a` as intended

```
$ echo a | gsed "s/\(\w*\)/\1x/"
ax
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, by gnu sed,

```
sed -E 's/^(fooAction)s: (typeof \1Creators)/\1s: Partial<\2>/' d
```